# Best Practice for Lists of Complex Types in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my first SO question, and it's less of a "how do I do this" and more of a "what is the cleanest way to do this", because there are several approaches I see but none of them seem very appealing to me.

This is a bit of a complicated issue to describe. Essentially, I have an Add/Edit view that allows the user to edit the fields of some object. This object is pretty complex: it has some fields, and it has a sub-list of complex objects. Each complex object is about 40 fields large (mostly checkboxes, radio buttons and dates/times). I have represented this as a select list:

[image]
<sub>(source: [fortheloot.com](http://fortheloot.com/public/pictures/sub-items.png))</sub>

The **Add** button spawns the dialog with the various fields.

The question comes here. When the user accepts the dialog, and the dialog closes, I now have to store this data somewhere, so that the user can edit it further or add other sub-items before actually submitting the form.

The most obvious way to do this is to create a set of hidden fields for every sub-object. So, adding a sub-item would add 40-something hidden elements to the `<form>` element. Add 10 sub-items and you have 400 hidden fields. This will work fine, and will bind to this model if the fields are named properly:

```
public class AddEditModel
{
  [Display(Name = "ID")]
  public int? Id { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Name")]
  [Required]
  [StringLength(100)]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public IList<EntryModel> Entries { get; set; }
  public class EntryModel { /* fields */ }
}
```

On the model binding side of things, this seems to look pretty good, but from the client side, I'm having to keep track of hundreds of DOM elements and this seems cumbersome to me. Loading and unloading the dialog's various form elements from 40 other elements seems ... like it could be better.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to just store the data as a javascript object on the `<option>` element using either `data-` HTML 5 attributes or jQuery's `data()` function, which are really one and the same. This would make the javascript side of things much cleaner, but it wouldn't automatically bind to the model on postback.

If there was a way to have the best of both worlds -- storing a single JS object on the `<option>` element, or even a single `<input type="hidden" />` element (per sub-item) -- that would still bind to the model properly on postback, I'd feel this issue resolved.

Comment: Dannngg. Good question, tough scenario. +1 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will still need an html field (type=hidden) in order to post this data back to the server. (You could use an ajax post but this probably isn't a great idea)

I would suggest designing a reasonable object model to contain these data structures, and serializing the object model each time you make a change it to json with [stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Then when you post back the form, the json will be sent to the server and you can deserialise the whole object model to a set of classes written in c# (which can mimic the object model you had in javascript) using the JavaScriptSerializer classes

Edit:

To deserialize a json string, you can use the following code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
var c = js.Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
return View(c);
```

If you post back json as the post message body, (e.g. an $.ajax, or $.post method) then binding will occur automatically with MVC3, you simply have to specify the correct content type: application/json in the post; follow the link in my comment below for more details as to how this works.

Martin

Comment: So, you would use a custom model binder to accomplish the JSON deserialization of that part of the model?

Comment: JsonValueProviderFactory, which is now registered by default in MVC3 can bind with json objects automatically, take a look at this post (though you can skip some of it if you're using MVC3): http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Comment: Hmmm. So your approach would be to POST the entire form as a single JSON object and let the MVC model binder detect this based on content-type. Interesting. I'd like to still allow the browser to do a normal FORM post.  It's sounding more and more like I need a custom model binder ..

Comment: You can keep the json string in a hidden field and bind a single string parameter to this field. You'd then be able to deserialize it using the classes I mentioned above in one more step to get the object graph. This wouldn't need a custom model binder and would be the regular form postback

Comment: Ultimately, I used this approach. I'm not terribly happy with it, but it works for now.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using an javascript framework like backbone or knockout? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112899/knockout-js-vs-backbone-js-vs

Comment: to question author: stop for a minute and take a close look at knockout.js

Comment: I rewrote this code last week to use Knockout. I came around. It just took 3.5 years.

Answer (score 1):

Since we're going with javascript all the way through, I would stick with javascript behavior for the postback as well. As you enter new items into the list, I would continue to build up a muftidimensional javascript array, then convert the array to json before sending it via an ajax post to your MVC route.

As long as the json object conforms to the naming standards of your model, MVC will already do the implicit model binding before it gets to the action method.

What's the easiest and most elegant way to do this? **Knockout.js!** In knockout, you'd create an observable collection and add to your collection without the grubby syntax of javascript arrays. Then you would call the knockout toJSON method to convert the collection to json before issuing the ajax post.

I'd highly recommend the watching PluralSight video on Knockout and then downloading the source code.

I'd write a sample, but I have to get back to work :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I really need to look at Knockout. Can you link me to the video you're talking about? Google turns up tons of results.

Comment: go to pluralsight.com, and you'll see a knockout video under the javascript category. pluralsight is a paid service, but i highly recommend...